# Tweaked .profile. Ubuntu 14.04LTS changed to Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome on RESTART. Unable to login to gnome also

Tags: 14.04, gnome, login

I made a few changes in the PATH in .profile. On restart, gnome booted up with my username. But on entering the password, it goes into a loop and I am unable to login.

Answer (score 0):

First login in command line ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

Then reset your  `.profile` file (with the 1st command making a backup) :

```
cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.backup
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
```

Reboot and everything should work properly.

Comment: I would have suggested to cp back the backup file he made. Your command should also include making a backup of ~/.profile in case there are changes in there that where made prior to the  malformed ones ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind plz do let me know of the command line which needs to be added and where its to be inserted in the above set of 2 command lines

Comment: Just do what I said.  1) Open the terminal. 2) Login 3) Paste the two command and it is done.

Comment: Hello, thanks Rinz and hg8 for the assistance. I need to let you know how it went wrong. I was using 14.04 LTS. Then i tweeked the .profile by adding multiple paths. When I did restart it booted ubuntu gnome directly. I find a usename, but on entering password it loops back. Hence trying set the .profile

Comment: Now, i keyed in the first cp line. it said

Comment: command 'cp' available in '/bin/cp'. the command could not be located bcoz '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable. cp:command not found...... Plz suggest how i can restore and login to ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: then do `/usr/bin/cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile`

Comment: shows-    -bash: /usr/bin/cp : no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

try to login from terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type your username and password and revert your changes in `.profile` using `nano`

Comment: I need to let you know how it went wrong. I was using 14.04 LTS. Then i tweeked the .profile by adding multiple paths. When I did restart it booted ubuntu gnome directly. I find a usename, but on entering password it loops back. Hence trying set the .profile

Comment: Now, i keyed in the nano. it said command 'nano' available in '/bin/nano' & '/usr/bin/nano'. the command could not be located bcoz '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable. nano:command not found.....